# Stings coming back as name error

Tags: python

I have some code I messing around with.. Very new to python and coding in general, however I stumped on this one.

I defined a function, and got some user input from that. When I try to print the input, I get a NameError: name 'my_name' is not defined.

Here is the code..

```
  #New Program
  #Written by Chris Nelson of Cnelson Creations

  #This code obtains some basic information from the user
   def questions():
    if userinput == "Y":
        my_name = input("What is your name? ")`enter code here`
        my_age = input("What is your age? ")
        my_urname = input("Please pick a username.. ")
        my_psword = input("Please pick a password.. ")
    elif userinput == "N":
        print ("Sorry we need the information to continue..")
        print ("... Goodbye")
        exit()
    else:
        print ("Not a valid choice.. Goodbye!")
        exit()
   print ("We need to obtain some information from you before going forward")
   print ("Is this ok? Enter Y for 'yes' or N for 'No'...")
   userinput = input("Please enter Y or N ")
   questions() #This code runs the function listed above..
   print ("Great we have some information from you!")
   print ("Lets confirm it is the correct information.. ")
   print ('{}, {}, {}, {}, is this information correct?'.format(my_name, my_age, my_urname, my_psword))
```

Comment: You have **scope** issues.

Comment: If you could, could you elaborate? Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `my_name` inside a function which will go into local scope. Look at this question for a [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules). You have multiple ways to correct this

- For `my_name` and the other variables defined in the function to be visible you will have to define them outside your function.
- Or add the global declaration inside your function

  `global my_name,my_age,my_urname,my_psword`
- Or use the famous *Tuple packing and Sequence Unpacking*

  Have a statement at the end of your `if` condition in the function

  `return (my_name,my_age,my_urname,my_psword)` 
  and the have `my_name,my_age,my_urname,my_psword = questions()` in your function call.
- Or print the values in the function itself, Like you have yourself suggested

Comment: Ah, I understand..
Or just print the displaying of that information inside the function?

Comment: Or pass them as arguments to the function.

Comment: return is  a much better way +1

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for that. But I'm afraid that the OP is still a beginner. :( Then he will have only the first two options :)

Comment: @BhargavRao, better to learn good methods from the start than to learn bad and try to correct them later.

Comment: @ChristopherNelson Did you find the solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of that you attempt to print the `my_name` outside the function . As you defied it inside the function so it is in local (scope) namespace (**variables inside a function has local scope (means that you couldn't access them outside the function and on another scopes )**)! if you want to access it outside the function you need to define it as `global` . by adding `global my_name` at the top level of your function, also as you wanted to access to another variables you need to do something like `my_name` for those .

But as amore efficient way you could return those variable inside your function :

```
def questions():
    if userinput == "Y":
        my_name = input("What is your name? ")`enter code here`
        my_age = input("What is your age? ")
        my_urname = input("Please pick a username.. ")
        my_psword = input("Please pick a password.. ")
    elif userinput == "N":
        print ("Sorry we need the information to continue..")
        print ("... Goodbye")
        exit()
    else:
        print ("Not a valid choice.. Goodbye!")
        exit()
    return (my_name,my_age,my_urname,my_psword)
```

and outside the function you could do the following assignment :

```
my_name, my_age, my_urname, my_psword= questions()
```

Answer (score -3):

Add *global my_name,my_age,my_urname,my_psword*

```
def questions():
    global my_name,my_age,my_urname,my_psword
    if userinput == "Y":
        my_name = input("What is your name? ")`enter code here`
        my_age = input("What is your age? ")
        my_urname = input("Please pick a username.. ")
        my_psword = input("Please pick a password.. ")
```

So you can use that variables outside of function too.

Comment: There are always better ways than global

Comment: So should we warn Guido van Rossum about lets remove _global_ from Python ? For example eval() is a dangerous func but if you know how to use it than there is no problem.

Comment: But he should learn what _global_ does too, and its a good answer In my opinion, as you see all another answers same.

Comment: Sir, Im not arguing. I just saying that, he should learn _global_ if he going to work with functions.. So my answer is with _global_.

Comment: Opinions are not need. qqvc's answer is almost the same as Bhargav Rao's answer. They both said that adding a global statement is needed.

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham, didn't you not read that he said that: "Or add the global declaration inside your function"?

Comment: Why you guys arguing here? What is your problem. Padraic, if you consider answers which one get most upvote then you are really missunderstand this website. There is thousands of answers in SO which they doesnt deserve any up vote, just some fans upvoting them.